# How to get rid of Â when exporting report to CSV file

Tags: civireport

How to get rid of Â when exporting report to CSV file. running report

Comment: Welcome to CiviCRM SE! I'm guessing that this is the same as I have seen and that the unwanted character precedes a current symbol (£ in my case). Its always good to give as much information as you can. Its always good to give the version of CiviCRM (though this has been like this for ages for me) and also what CRM you are using (may well be relevant).

Comment: Just tried it on the WordPress demo site and I didn't get the problem! So I'm wondering if its something to do with the character encoding settings on my site.

Answer (score 2):

This should be solved in version 5.22. It's usually non-english characters where Excel needs a special header to be able to determine the encoding.

See https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/16117 and https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1424